# Ошибка 6 в Overlapped WSARecv

Tags: c++, winsock, iocp

Пишу новый сервер на IOCP. В потоке приёма новых подключений вызываю `WSARecv` (после успешного `accept` естественно). Срабатывает `WSARecv` с 3-5 попытки для клиента на C++, для браузера вообще ни разу не срабатывало (подключается по WebSocket). Причина всегда одна и та же - результат **6** после вызова `WSAGetLastError()`.

Лог сервера выглядит примерно так (большие значения `transferred` не понятно откуда, актуальная информация в `Received XX bytes from ...` и `Sent XX bytes to ...`):

> To stop server press ESC
>  Client 324 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv
>   error 6 on socket 324
>  Client 328 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv
>   error 6 on socket 328
>  Client 332 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv
>   error 6 on socket 332
>  Client 336 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Thread 8
>   completed operation for client 336 (IP 127.0.0.1), transferred
>   62323228 bytes
>  Received 25 bytes from 336
>  Thread 7 completed
>   operation for client 336 (IP 127.0.0.1), transferred 59963932
>   bytes
>  Sent 1 bytes to 336
>  Thread 8 completed operation for
>   client 336 (IP 127.0.0.1), transferred 62323228 bytes
>  Received 11
>   bytes from 336
>  Thread 7 completed operation for client 336 (IP
>   127.0.0.1), transferred 59963932 bytes
>  Sent 1 bytes to 336
>  Thread 7 completed operation for client 336 (IP 127.0.0.1),
>   transferred 59963932 bytes
>  Client 356 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>   Thread 7 completed operation for client 356 (IP 127.0.0.1),
>   transferred 59963932 bytes
>  Received 533 bytes from 356
>  Thread
>   8 completed operation for client 356 (IP 127.0.0.1), transferred
>   62323228 bytes
>  Sent 129 bytes to 356
>  Thread 8 completed
>   operation for client 356 (IP 127.0.0.1), transferred 62323228
>   bytes
>  Client 360 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv error 6 on socket
>   360
>  Client 364 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv error 6 on socket
>   364
>  Client 368 added (IP 127.0.0.1)
>  Recv error 6 on socket
>   368
>  Client 372 added (IP 127.0.0.1)

Первые три попытки проводил один и тот же клиент. На четвёртый раз пошёл обмен. Последние неудачные попытки были от браузера - он вообще не смог подключиться.

Код принимающего потока:

```
unsigned int __stdcall AcceptThread(void * param){
    SOCKET ServerSocket = (SOCKET)param;
    WSANETWORKEVENTS WSAEvents;

    while(WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(EventShutdown, 0)){
        if( WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT != WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &EventAccept, FALSE, 100, FALSE) ){
            WSAEnumNetworkEvents(ServerSocket, EventAccept, &WSAEvents);
            if((WSAEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT) && (0 == WSAEvents.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT])){            
                client *Client = new client();
                int addrlen = sizeof(Client->address);
                //Accept remote connection attempt from the client
                if( INVALID_SOCKET == Client->Socket(accept(ServerSocket,(sockaddr*)&(Client->address),&addrlen)) ) delete Client;
                else if( NULL != CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)Client->Socket(), hIOCP, (DWORD)Client, 0) ){
                    AddClient(Client);
                    DWORD flag = 0;
                    // Init receiving
                    int result = WSARecv(Client->Socket(), Client->RecvContext(), 1, Client->Rcvd(), &flag, Client->Overlapped(), NULL);
                    int err = WSAGetLastError();
                    if((SOCKET_ERROR == result) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != err)){
                        printf("Recv error %d on socket %d\n", err, Client->Socket());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("AcceptThread closed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

С чем эта ошибка может быть связанна? Почему `WSA_INVALID_HANDLE`, и из-за какой магии это пропадает с n-ной попытки подключения?

*PS: вся необходимая инициализация выполняется до создания потока с `AcceptThread`. Если бы не создался порт завершения или была ошибка при `WSACreateEvent` или `WSAEventSelect` на подготовленном принимающем сокете, до потока приёма дело бы не дошло.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ох и Microsoft... Оказывается эта ошибка, `WSA_INVALID_HANDLE`, касается поля `hEvent` структуры `OVERLAPPED`.

Из MSDN

> A handle to the event that will be set to a signaled state by the
>   system when the operation has completed. The user must initialize this
>   member either to zero or a valid event handle using the CreateEvent
>   function before passing this structure to any overlapped functions

Я вот всегда, когда пишу свои структуры и классы, в их конструкторах инициализирую поля-указатели `nullptr`-ом. В WinAPI такие "мелочи" решили оставить на

> user must

))

Comment: А что вы хотели от С апи? А вообще я бы вам посоветовал использовать какие-нибудь готовые средства, хотя бы тот же boost::asio. а то с ручным управлением ошибками, ресурсами и С-style кастами типа `(DWORD) Client` далеко не уедите. И не лезьте в многопоточный код пока оно не заработает нормально в одном потоке.